# Warn if using an object as a boolean expression in conditionals

Tags: objective-c, clang

Is there a clang flag to warn when you use e.g. an object in an `if` statement instead of a boolean expression?

I googled for this but couldn't find anything. This would help prevent mistakes like this, especially when using editor generated Core Data classes:

```
NSNumber *n = @(YES)

if (n) { // should be n.boolValue instead of n
    ...
}
```

I found an "Implicit Boolean Conversions" option in Xcode but that doesn't seem to be it (I double checked).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no short-hander for this and there cannot be.

A.

`if` comes from classical C. In classical C there is no boolean type. (They extended C in 99, but did not touch `if`.) Basically everything !=0 is true, everything ==0 is false.

B.

`n` is no object. It is an object reference. You need expressions like you have to check, whether the object reference points to `nil`. With your suggestion there would be no difference between "no object" and "an object containing NO".

Comment: I want to enforce use of "boolValue" where appropriate so that errors like above would be caught, not implicit conversion of @(NO) to NO.

Comment: If you mean that one would need to convert all their `if (!object)` code to `if (object != nil)` that sucks yeah, but I don't use the shorthand form.

Comment: 1. "Where appropiate" is under what condition? 2. How can the compiler know, whether a test on the reference is meant or a test on the result of the message `booleanValue` to the object the reference points to? 3. What is meant in your case? Looking only on the source code (and not your explanation around), I cannot say that. The compiler can? 4. If the expression `object` would be a boolean expression under $whatever condition, `object  != nil` would be a comparision of a boolean expression to an object reference.